# Monitoring keyboard activity in C# while my application is in the background

Tags: c#, .net, windows, keyboard, keyboard-hook

First of all I need to make it clear that I have no interest in keylogging.

I need a way to monitor keyboard activity at the most basic level while my application is in the background.
I don't need to know which keys, I don't need to save any data, I don't need or plan to hide my application at all, all I need is to know when keys are pressed and invoke a method.

I'm looking for the simplest way to do this possible, I know a reasonable amount of C# but nothing too complex as most of my knowledge is self-taught.

I've looked around for some appropriate ways of doing this and I've found nothing useful. All I've found is a bunch of people saying "No, that's illegal" on forums and source code for in depth keyloggers.

If any of you could advise me on a way to achieve this then I would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to use Window Hooks:

[Low-Level Keyboard Hook in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx)

But beware, Windows security, may be protecting us from doing what you want!

Answer (score 5):

You can monitor keyboard and mouse activity in the background with the Nuget package [MouseKeyHook](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MouseKeyHook) ([GitHub](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook)).

This code detects when a key is pressed:

```
    private IKeyboardMouseEvents _globalHook;

    private void Subscribe()
    {
        if (_globalHook == null)
        {
            // Note: for the application hook, use the Hook.AppEvents() instead
            _globalHook = Hook.GlobalEvents();
            _globalHook.KeyPress += GlobalHookKeyPress;
        }
    }

    private static void GlobalHookKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("KeyPress: \t{0}", e.KeyChar);
    }

    private void Unsubscribe()
    {
        if (_globalHook != null)
        {
            _globalHook.KeyPress -= GlobalHookKeyPress;
            _globalHook.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

You will need to call `Subscribe()` to start listening, and `Unsubscribe()` to stop listening. Obviously you need to modify `GlobalHookKeyPress()` to do useful work.

I needed this functionality in order to write a utility which will turn on the keyboard backlight on a Lenovo Thinkpad when any key is pressed, including CTRL (which `KeyPress`  doesn't catch). For this purpose, I had to monitor for key down instead. The code is the same except we attach to a different event...

```
    _globalHook.KeyDown += GlobalHookOnKeyDown;
```

and the event handler signature is different:

```
    private static void GlobalHookOnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("KeyDown: \t{0}", e.KeyCode);
    }
```

The library can also [detect specific key combinations and sequences](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook/blob/vNext/keycomb.md). For example:

```
    Hook.GlobalEvents().OnCombination(new Dictionary<Combination, Action>
    {
        { Combination.TriggeredBy(Keys.A).Control(), () => { Console.WriteLine("You Pressed CTRL+A"); } },
        { Combination.FromString("Shift+Alt+Enter"), () => { Console.WriteLine("You Pressed FULL SCREEN"); } }
    });
```

Comment: Working like a boss!

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft tells you [How to: Handle Keyboard Input at the Form Level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171538.aspx).  As long as you handle the same event(s) this works for any non web application.

You should also take a look at the other questions here on SO, such as [Handling Input from a Keyboard Wedge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274842/handling-input-from-a-keyboard-wedge)

Comment: That's for when the application is in the foreground though isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I need to monitor it in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You could register Windows Hot Key with RegisterHotKey windows API, look at this blog post :

http://www.liensberger.it/web/blog/?p=207