# C# replace certain string when typing in any application

Tags: c#

I want to make an application that will replace a certain string when I type in any textfield of any application (online textboxes, notepad, word, email, etc..)

For example if I'm writing in notepad++ and I type [for] and press space or enter I want my C# application to work in background, access the field and replace that string with a predefined string in my C# code.

The result would for example be:

```
for($i = 0; $i < X; $i++)
{
   // ....
}
```

For example if I'm writing a word document and I input [FIRSTPAGE] I would want that to be replaced with a random string I setup early.

Later on I will setup an app that will let me change these on the fly.

I tried searching google but I found no information on anything similar. 
I just need to find a way to replace a string in any textfield.

Hope this makes sense. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Tried the documentation? STring.Replace, Regex - not exactly stuff not directly in there. Naturally noone will deliver you a complete solution.

Comment: @TomTom Those aren't really relevant.

Comment: you can probably find some spellcheck software and add values to the lookup database to "autocorrect" to the strings you are looking for

Comment: OP, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383569/monitoring-keyboard-activity-in-c-sharp-while-my-application-is-in-the-backgroun) to get you started. Not flagging as duplicate as it only answers half your question (mechanics of hooking, not how to monitor over time & replace).

Comment: @Rawling They are totally relevant given the description of the problem you gave. Obviously you have a problem asking the right question, because "rplace string in application" is a little thing people do as training in week 2 of playing with C#, latest. And if you want something a lot more complex then - no, not many people do text editors.

Comment: Take a look at AutoHotKey. I think you can compile its scripts into standalone applications.

Comment: @TomTom I'm not the asker, genius. Wanting to monitor keypresses and replace them in realtime is probably not going to be achieved through `string` or `Regex` `.Replace` methods.

Comment: @Rawling is correct. And I'm not even near asking for a complete solution. I'm just asking for the most important part: a way to monitor whats written in another application and replace that with another string.

Answer (score 2):

Create a global keyboard hook, [C# : Keyboard Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391025/c-sharp-keyboard-hook) shows how you can do it.

Once hook is created monitor handle the keylog for typed word. Once the typed word is found use [`SendKeys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to send keystrokes virtually.

Answer (score 0):

There's a really cool library called **Scintilla.NET** - http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/

It's usually used for building your own code editor with syntax highlighting support.
But it has the auto-suggest feature you are after, i.e:

[image]

Comment: The OP is more concerned about editing a textbox that not owned by his application.