# How to read keyboard input while form is in the background c#

Tags: c#

I need to be able to read keyboard input while my form is in the background (not necessarily hidden). There are simmilar questions here but I need to be albe to determine witch key is pressed and I need to get its value as "Key" not int (stuff like 0x00357 and I have no idea what that is). Specifically I need to check if key determined by user is currently pressed. How can I do that?

Comment: search **windows hook** and it is not that simple but plenty of tutorials.

Comment: note also that some antivirus block programs that use this kind of hook: reading the keyboard input directed to another application is what a malicius keylogger would do

Comment: Possible dupicate of [Monitoring keyboard activity in C# while my application is in the background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383569/monitoring-keyboard-activity-in-c-sharp-while-my-application-is-in-the-backgroun)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few years later than you asked, but this is what I used when creating an app that would listen to key presses, and anything in a predefined list would be mirrored to other background processes to enable multi-boxing in a game.

There is a great keyboard listener at [Ciantic's Github](https://gist.github.com/Ciantic/471698), and in case the link is invalid then here's the code -

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Ownskit.Utils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Listens keyboard globally.
    /// 
    /// <remarks>Uses WH_KEYBOARD_LL.</remarks>
    /// </summary>
    public class KeyboardListener : IDisposable
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates global keyboard listener.
        /// </summary>
        public KeyboardListener()
        {
            // Dispatcher thread handling the KeyDown/KeyUp events.
            this.dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

            // We have to store the LowLevelKeyboardProc, so that it is not garbage collected runtime
            hookedLowLevelKeyboardProc = (InterceptKeys.LowLevelKeyboardProc)LowLevelKeyboardProc;

            // Set the hook
            hookId = InterceptKeys.SetHook(hookedLowLevelKeyboardProc);

            // Assign the asynchronous callback event
            hookedKeyboardCallbackAsync = new KeyboardCallbackAsync(KeyboardListener_KeyboardCallbackAsync);
        }

        private Dispatcher dispatcher;

        /// <summary>
        /// Destroys global keyboard listener.
        /// </summary>
        ~KeyboardListener()
        {
            Dispose();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Fired when any of the keys is pressed down.
        /// </summary>
        public event RawKeyEventHandler KeyDown;

        /// <summary>
        /// Fired when any of the keys is released.
        /// </summary>
        public event RawKeyEventHandler KeyUp;

        #region Inner workings

        /// <summary>
        /// Hook ID
        /// </summary>
        private IntPtr hookId = IntPtr.Zero;

        /// <summary>
        /// Asynchronous callback hook.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="character">Character</param>
        /// <param name="keyEvent">Keyboard event</param>
        /// <param name="vkCode">VKCode</param>
        private delegate void KeyboardCallbackAsync(InterceptKeys.KeyEvent keyEvent, int vkCode, string character);

        /// <summary>
        /// Actual callback hook.
        /// 
        /// <remarks>Calls asynchronously the asyncCallback.</remarks>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="nCode"></param>
        /// <param name="wParam"></param>
        /// <param name="lParam"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        private IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            string chars = "";

            if (nCode >= 0)
                if (wParam.ToUInt32() == (int)InterceptKeys.KeyEvent.WM_KEYDOWN ||
                    wParam.ToUInt32() == (int)InterceptKeys.KeyEvent.WM_KEYUP ||
                    wParam.ToUInt32() == (int)InterceptKeys.KeyEvent.WM_SYSKEYDOWN ||
                    wParam.ToUInt32() == (int)InterceptKeys.KeyEvent.WM_SYSKEYUP)
                {
                    // Captures the character(s) pressed only on WM_KEYDOWN
                    chars = InterceptKeys.VKCodeToString((uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam), 
                        (wParam.ToUInt32() == (int)InterceptKeys.KeyEvent.WM_KEYDOWN ||
                        wParam.ToUInt32() == (int)InterceptKeys.KeyEvent.WM_SYSKEYDOWN));

                    hookedKeyboardCallbackAsync.BeginInvoke((InterceptKeys.KeyEvent)wParam.ToUInt32(), Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam), chars, null, null);
                }

            return InterceptKeys.CallNextHookEx(hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Event to be invoked asynchronously (BeginInvoke) each time key is pressed.
        /// </summary>
        private KeyboardCallbackAsync hookedKeyboardCallbackAsync;

        /// <summary>
        /// Contains the hooked callback in runtime.
        /// </summary>
        private InterceptKeys.LowLevelKeyboardProc hookedLowLevelKeyboardProc;

        /// <summary>
        /// HookCallbackAsync procedure that calls accordingly the KeyDown or KeyUp events.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="keyEvent">Keyboard event</param>
        /// <param name="vkCode">VKCode</param>
        /// <param name="character">Character as string.</param>
        void KeyboardListener_KeyboardCallbackAsync(InterceptKeys.KeyEvent keyEvent, int vkCode, string character)
        {
            switch (keyEvent)
            {
                // KeyDown events
                case InterceptKeys.KeyEvent.WM_KEYDOWN:
                    if (KeyDown != null)
                        dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new RawKeyEventHandler(KeyDown), this, new RawKeyEventArgs(vkCode, false, character));
                    break;
                case InterceptKeys.KeyEvent.WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
                    if (KeyDown != null)
                        dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new RawKeyEventHandler(KeyDown), this, new RawKeyEventArgs(vkCode, true, character));
                    break;

                // KeyUp events
                case InterceptKeys.KeyEvent.WM_KEYUP:
                    if (KeyUp != null)
                        dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new RawKeyEventHandler(KeyUp), this, new RawKeyEventArgs(vkCode, false, character));
                    break;
                case InterceptKeys.KeyEvent.WM_SYSKEYUP:
                    if (KeyUp != null)
                        dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new RawKeyEventHandler(KeyUp), this, new RawKeyEventArgs(vkCode, true, character));
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region IDisposable Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Disposes the hook.
        /// <remarks>This call is required as it calls the UnhookWindowsHookEx.</remarks>
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            InterceptKeys.UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookId);
        }

        #endregion
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raw KeyEvent arguments.
    /// </summary>
    public class RawKeyEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// VKCode of the key.
        /// </summary>
        public int VKCode;

        /// <summary>
        /// WPF Key of the key.
        /// </summary>
        public Key Key;

        /// <summary>
        /// Is the hitted key system key.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsSysKey;

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert to string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns string representation of this key, if not possible empty string is returned.</returns>
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Character;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Unicode character of key pressed.
        /// </summary>
        public string Character;

        /// <summary>
        /// Create raw keyevent arguments.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="VKCode"></param>
        /// <param name="isSysKey"></param>
        /// <param name="Character">Character</param>
        public RawKeyEventArgs(int VKCode, bool isSysKey, string Character)
        {
            this.VKCode = VKCode;
            this.IsSysKey = isSysKey;
            this.Character = Character;
            this.Key = System.Windows.Input.KeyInterop.KeyFromVirtualKey(VKCode);
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raw keyevent handler.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">sender</param>
    /// <param name="args">raw keyevent arguments</param>
    public delegate void RawKeyEventHandler(object sender, RawKeyEventArgs args);

    #region WINAPI Helper class
    /// <summary>
    /// Winapi Key interception helper class.
    /// </summary>
    internal static class InterceptKeys
    {
        public delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        public static int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;

        /// <summary>
        /// Key event
        /// </summary>
        public enum KeyEvent : int {    
            /// <summary>
            /// Key down
            /// </summary>
            WM_KEYDOWN = 256,

            /// <summary>
            /// Key up
            /// </summary>
            WM_KEYUP = 257,

            /// <summary>
            /// System key up
            /// </summary>
            WM_SYSKEYUP = 261,

            /// <summary>
            /// System key down
            /// </summary>
            WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 260
        }

        public static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        #region Convert VKCode to string
        // Note: Sometimes single VKCode represents multiple chars, thus string. 
        // E.g. typing "^1" (notice that when pressing 1 the both characters appear, 
        // because of this behavior, "^" is called dead key)

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int ToUnicodeEx(uint wVirtKey, uint wScanCode, byte[] lpKeyState, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] System.Text.StringBuilder pwszBuff, int cchBuff, uint wFlags, IntPtr dwhkl);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool GetKeyboardState(byte[] lpKeyState);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern uint MapVirtualKeyEx(uint uCode, uint uMapType, IntPtr dwhkl);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetKeyboardLayout(uint dwLayout);

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool AttachThreadInput(uint idAttach, uint idAttachTo, bool fAttach);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern uint GetCurrentThreadId();

        private static uint lastVKCode = 0;
        private static uint lastScanCode = 0;
        private static byte[] lastKeyState = new byte[255];
        private static bool lastIsDead = false;

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert VKCode to Unicode.
        /// <remarks>isKeyDown is required for because of keyboard state inconsistencies!</remarks>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="VKCode">VKCode</param>
        /// <param name="isKeyDown">Is the key down event?</param>
        /// <returns>String representing single unicode character.</returns>
        public static string VKCodeToString(uint VKCode, bool isKeyDown)
        {
            // ToUnicodeEx needs StringBuilder, it populates that during execution.
            System.Text.StringBuilder sbString = new System.Text.StringBuilder(5);

            byte[] bKeyState = new byte[255];
            bool bKeyStateStatus;
            bool isDead = false;

            // Gets the current windows window handle, threadID, processID
            IntPtr currentHWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
            uint currentProcessID;
            uint currentWindowThreadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(currentHWnd, out currentProcessID);

            // This programs Thread ID
            uint thisProgramThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();

            // Attach to active thread so we can get that keyboard state
            if (AttachThreadInput(thisProgramThreadId, currentWindowThreadID , true))
            {
                // Current state of the modifiers in keyboard
                bKeyStateStatus = GetKeyboardState(bKeyState);

                // Detach
                AttachThreadInput(thisProgramThreadId, currentWindowThreadID, false);
            }
            else
            {
                // Could not attach, perhaps it is this process?
                bKeyStateStatus = GetKeyboardState(bKeyState);
            }

            // On failure we return empty string.
            if (!bKeyStateStatus)
                return "";

            // Gets the layout of keyboard
            IntPtr HKL = GetKeyboardLayout(currentWindowThreadID);

            // Maps the virtual keycode
            uint lScanCode = MapVirtualKeyEx(VKCode, 0, HKL);

            // Keyboard state goes inconsistent if this is not in place. In other words, we need to call above commands in UP events also.
            if (!isKeyDown)
                return "";

            // Converts the VKCode to unicode
            int relevantKeyCountInBuffer = ToUnicodeEx(VKCode, lScanCode, bKeyState, sbString, sbString.Capacity, (uint)0, HKL);

            string ret = "";

            switch (relevantKeyCountInBuffer)
            {
                // Dead keys (^,`...)
                case -1:
                    isDead = true;

                    // We must clear the buffer because ToUnicodeEx messed it up, see below.
                    ClearKeyboardBuffer(VKCode, lScanCode, HKL);
                    break;

                case 0:
                    break;

                // Single character in buffer
                case 1:
                    ret = sbString[0].ToString();
                    break;

                // Two or more (only two of them is relevant)
                case 2:
                default:
                    ret = sbString.ToString().Substring(0, 2);
                    break;
            }

            // We inject the last dead key back, since ToUnicodeEx removed it.
            // More about this peculiar behavior see e.g: 
            //   http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/System/Windows__Programming/Q_23453780.html
            //   http://blogs.msdn.com/michkap/archive/2005/01/19/355870.aspx
            //   http://blogs.msdn.com/michkap/archive/2007/10/27/5717859.aspx
            if (lastVKCode != 0 && lastIsDead)
            {
                System.Text.StringBuilder sbTemp = new System.Text.StringBuilder(5);
                ToUnicodeEx(lastVKCode, lastScanCode, lastKeyState, sbTemp, sbTemp.Capacity, (uint)0, HKL);
                lastVKCode = 0;

                return ret;
            }

            // Save these
            lastScanCode = lScanCode;
            lastVKCode = VKCode;
            lastIsDead = isDead;
            lastKeyState = (byte[])bKeyState.Clone();

            return ret;
        }

        private static void ClearKeyboardBuffer(uint vk, uint sc, IntPtr hkl)
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(10);

            int rc;
            do {
                byte[] lpKeyStateNull = new Byte[255];
                rc = ToUnicodeEx(vk, sc, lpKeyStateNull, sb, sb.Capacity, 0, hkl);
            } while(rc < 0);
        }
        #endregion
    }
    #endregion
}
```

From the author, this is the usage -

Usage in WPF:

```
App.xaml:
<Application ...
    Startup="Application_Startup"
    Exit="Application_Exit">
    ...
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    KeyboardListener KListener = new KeyboardListener();

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        KListener.KeyDown += new RawKeyEventHandler(KListener_KeyDown);
    }

    void KListener_KeyDown(object sender, RawKeyEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args.Key.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(args.ToString()); // Prints the text of pressed button, takes in account big and small letters. E.g. "Shift+a" => "A"
    }

    private void Application_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        KListener.Dispose();
    }
}
```

If you also need to listen for KeyUp events then you can create a listener for that as well. The RawKeyEventArgs that is generated contains the key name, character pressed, and virtual key code. You can use any of these to compare with your existing list that you're wanting to respond to, and react accordingly. If you need to verify what key presses will look like then you can display a message box of anything entered and build yourself a list from there.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Although I have long since figured it myself, This would have been exactly what I was looking for!