# Selection, Sorting and Highlighting Elements in the selected order using PickObjects() method (Revit API)

Tags: revit-api, revitpythonshell, pyrevit

Is there a method Revit API where I can select elements in order, highlighting the elements selection.

Please note, Selection.PickObjects() does the selection & highlighting but does not save the elements in the order of Selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is exactly as you say. No, the Revit API does not provide a built-in method providing the functionality you require. You can implement it yourself by calling `PickObject` repeatedly in a loop and collecting the selected elements in your own sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way you can fix your problem is by using the following method.

```
public List<Element> GetElementsBySelection(UIDocument uiDoc)
{
    bool flag = true;
    List<Element> listElem = new List<Element>();
    do
    {
        try
        {
            Reference referencia = uiDoc.Selection.PickObject(ObjectType.Element);
            Element elem = uiDoc.Document.GetElement(referencia);
            listElem.Add(elem);
        }
        catch (Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.OperationCanceledException e)
        {
            flag = false;
        }

    } while (flag);

    return listElem;
}
```

This method ends when you press the "Esc" key. Other more elegant ways to detect when the key is pressed were discussed in the following forums: [Monitoring keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383569/monitoring-keyboard-activity-in-c-sharp-while-my-application-is-in-the-backgroun) and [Detect key press](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/detect-key-press/td-p/9827604).

I hope that it serves as a guide so that you can continue advancing in the development. Best regards.
Thanks to [Jeremy Tammik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3552305/jeremy-tammik) for the general idea to solve the problem.